# Can memory fragmentation cause an Arduino to run out of RAM even if the program uses less than half of the RAM?

Tags: memory-management, arduino, embedded

I am using the Arduino Nano every which has 6kB RAM and am confident that I can write my program to use less than half of the RAM. My program has some variables in the void loop, one of which is a 10 character string, which are overwritten 10 times a second. There are additional variables including <10 character strings in functions that are also over written 10 times a second).

**Surely, if I am using less than half of the RAM, then no matter how fragmented the RAM becomes, the memory allocator will always find holes large enough to fit the new data when some operation is performed on a variable?**

I have already heard that strings are frowned upon on Arduinos. It does surprise me since char arrays are perfectly capable of causing memory fragmentation. I don't want to swap my strings for char arrays because I am using serial.readstring() to read the entire string from the serial port. To work with char, I would need to use serial.read() which only receives 1 character, making the process far more cumbersome.

Comment: _"I would need to use serial.read() which only receives 1 character, making the process far more cumbersome."_ - It is hardly cumbersome to write a `readString()` wrapper using `Serial.read()` - write once, use many - you could have done that in less time than to post your question.

Comment: You need to be clear in this question that you are specifically referring to the Arduino `String` class rather than strings in general (which could otherwise be `std::string` or C-strings).

Comment: Just avoid the following and there will be no problems: dynamic allocation, C++, Arduino libs. If you simply love having problems other than those you encounter when doing the actual application, then bloated C++ libs is surely the way to go. More in-depth info about the many problems with dynamic allocation here: [Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286121)

Comment: The Arduino Nano according to https://store.arduino.cc/products/arduino-nano has 2K RAM - are you sure you have 6K or that it is a Nano?  That would certainly explain why you are running out of memory!

Comment: Hi Clifford, I am using the 'Nano every'. Its the same size pcb as the Nano but that's about the only similarity. it has more RAM, a different processor, 20 MHz clock, hardware interrupts on every digital pin.

Comment: Hi Lundin, avoiding dynamic memory allocation is easier said than done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want to swap my strings for char arrays because I am using serial.readstring()

`Serial.readString()` returns a `String` object, the internal buffer for which (from the [source](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-API/blob/master/api/String.cpp), because it is not documented) is dynamically allocated (and reallocated if the size increases).  Each allocation will be 8 byte aligned and include a block header which might be 8 bytes also, so the "overhead" space (that is space used but not available to the user of the allocated memory) for small allocations may be considerable in proportion to the user memory allocated.

Now you have to realise that dynamic memory allocations are from the *heap* and not all of your 6Kb will be allocated to the heap.  First the linker will allocate all static data objects, then the heap, and what is left will be the available stack.  On a 6Kb part there will hardly be any space for a usefully sized heap.

More generally using the system heap in embedded systems is a generally a bad idea -  in this case through lack of memory is an issue, but in all cases lack of real-time deterministic behaviour and error handling in the event of exhaustion at run-time are issues.

See https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/programming/memory-guide for information on code that can be used to determine the available heap space on your board and other information about memory usage on Arduino.

Fragmentation may not be the issue rather then simple memory exhaustion.  Fragmentation only occurs if you are repeatedly allocating and releasing blocks - if you allocate and never release, fragmentation will not occur.  In the case of a `String` object, it's memory is released when it is destroyed - deleted for a dynamically created object or goes out of scope for a local object.  `String` objects that are statically allocated will not be destroyed. Because `String` internally uses `realloc()` it can release memory if the string length increases - that *can* cause fragmentation perhaps, but that can be avoided by pre-allocationg sufficient capacity with `String.reserve()`.

The problem however is an easy one to solve and not at all "cumbersome" - at least not after you have written a suitable function (or copy and pasted it from here even).  e.g.:

```
char* SerialReadString( Serial& port, char* buffer, size_t length, int timeout )
{
    int start = millis() ;
    size_t ci = 0u ;
    while( ci < length - 1 && 
           (port.available() != 0 || millis() - start <= timeout) )
    {
        int ch = port.read() ;
        if( ch > 0 )
        {
            buffer[ci] = ch ;
            buffer[ci+1] = 0 ;
        }
    }

    return buffer ;
}
```

Comment: Although surprising, I should have suspected that serial.readString() involves dynamic memory because there is no buffer parameter. Thank you for posting a better answer.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer Clifford. I used the code in the link you provided to see if the amount of RAM used increases with time and it does not. I don't have any problems that I know of with my code but I want it to be capable of running indefinitely. My code only uses 7% of RAM and when finished won't be much longer. If I run into problems latter then I will give the serial.read() a try and use only char arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't using dynamic memory you won't get memory fragmentation. Dynamic memory is allocated when you use [`malloc()` and friends](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), or the `new` keyword, not typical in Arduino programs. Everything you mentioned is either on the stack which is a fixed size or allocated once for the life of the program.

Comment: It is ambiguous in the question, but the use of `serial.readString()`  in the question implies the use of the Arduino `String` class which calls `realloc()` internally to obtain space for the string and to increase the capacity as the string length increases.  While I doubt that fragmentation is the issue rather than a simple lack of sufficient heap, dynamic memory allocation is clearly occurring.